# Simple Go Pointer Explaination

Tags: pointers, go

Im working through a `Go Ebook`.

Here we are creating an array of pointers as so:

```
sampleArray := [5]*int{0: new(int), 1: new(int)}
```

As you can see index 0 and index 1 of `sampleArray` contain initialized integers whereas the remaining indexes contain uninitialized integers.

Then they do the following operation:

```
*sampleArray[0] = 10
*sampleArray[1] = 20
```

With that, the values of `sampleArray` should be:

```
[0] => address (integer pointer) -> 10
[1] => address (integer pointer) -> 20
[2] => nil (integer pointer)
[3] => nil (integer pointer)
[4] => nil (integer pointer)
```

My question is, why do we do this:

```
*sampleArray[0] = 10
*sampleArray[1] = 20
```

And not this:

```
sampleArray[0] = 10
sampleArray[1] = 20
```

To me it looks like we are assigning a value to a pointer which points to another pointer. Shouln't we be assigning the value to the actual memory reference?

Why not then?

```
&sampleArray[0] = 10
&sampleArray[1] = 20
```

Im extremely new to pointers so please any thourough assistance would be helpful

Comment: `sampleArray[0] = 10` is not gonna compile because `sampleArray[0]` is of type `*int` and `10` is of type `int`.

Comment: "Shouldn't we be assigning the value to the actual memory reference" is more or less what you're doing. This just happens to be the syntax for it.

Comment: @JimB can you provide a detailed explanation. Im still rough on references and memory pointers and such. a detailed explanation would be great

Comment: `*sampleArray[0] = 10` means to put the value `10` at the location pointed by `sampleArray[0]`. And it's only possible because you already have a pointer in `sampleArray[0]` : `*sampleArray[3] = 10` would fail.

Comment: @DenysSéguret can you please provide a detailed explanation

Comment: @mkopriva we actually initialize the array with index 0 as new(int)

Comment: "To me it looks like we are assigning a value to a pointer" it sounds a bit like you're confusing `*SomeType` with `*SomeVar`. In these two cases `*` is not one and the same @jkushner.

Comment: @mkopriva please provide detailed explanation

Comment: `new(int)` returns `*int` not `int`, so I'm not sure what your point is.

Comment: @jkushner: you keep saying that, but it's unclear what kind of explanation you require. Maybe read about [Address Operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators)?

Comment: @jkushner As we don't exactly what part you're confused about, it's hard to make an answer.

Comment: @JimB I just want to know why they assign the value to `*sampleArray[0]=10` instead of `sampleArray[0]=10`

Comment: @jkushner: it was said above, `ampleArray[0]` is of type `*int`, so you can't assign an integer to the pointer value.

Comment: @JimB I understand now. Quick Question. Does `&` (i believe thats a reference) play any role in this? If so, how?

Comment: Assuming you already have a variable v holding an integer, you could do  `sampleArray[2]=&v`

Comment: @jkushner: I don't understand the question, but it's probably explained in the first paragraph of the documentation I linked above. `&` takes the address of a value.

Comment: @jkushner https://play.golang.org/p/jySYlpXwcmt

Comment: @mkopriva PERFECT THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a good question.

The dereferencing operator `*` has a lower precedence than array access (which in C is equivalent to pointer deref). So `*a[x]` in Go means "dereference `a[x]`" and not "dereference `a` and take element  x".

Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: So in essence we are dereferencing *sampleArray[0] which then allows for assiging data to it

Comment: My only question is if its initialized as sampleArray int*[5]  and then accessed as *sampleArray[0] wouldnt that be essentially a double reference?

Comment: Should read: the `*` operator has _lower_ precedence. If it had higher precedence it _would_ mean "dereference a then take element x".

Comment: *So `*a[x]` in Go means "dereference `*a[x]`"* sounds like infinite recursion though.